# I'm working on a project with java and connecting it with database (oracle) it's about food delivery desktop application

Tags: java, sql, database

i have 3 table
First is Restaurant owner and it's primary key is Restaurant_NAME
Second is Meals and it's primary key is MEAL_NAME
Third is a table that is a relation between them called Restaurant_MEAL and it takes the two primary keys above as a foreign key.
I want to whenever a restaurant owner enters a new meal ; the restaurant name and the meal name will be stored in the table next to each other
Say resturant owner X which owns restaurant Y entered a sanwdwich meal, the table then should contain
Y | Sandwich

CODE :

```
try {
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "hr", "hr");
   String query = "INSERT INTO RESTURANT_MEAL (PRODUCT_NAME, RESTURANT_NAME)" + "values(?,?)";
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement insert = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    insert = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        insert.setString(1,  products.get(i).getProductName());
        insert.setString(2, businessName);
        insert.execute();
    }
    

    insert.execute();
    
    conn.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OUTPUT : it saves the meal in table meals and there's an error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

and nothing is saved in the relation table

Comment: Where does `businessName` come from?  Side note, not part of the problem, but you have `insert = conn.prepareStatement(query);` twice. There may also be a query error. Try changing the query portion: `RESTURANT_NAME)" + "values` to `RESTURANT_NAME) values`. (basically, eliminate the `+`)

Comment: Please see this related question. If it solves your problem, let me/us know and we can close your question as a duplicate

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.